# how to add page footer to PDF document using iTextSharp for pages generated in landscape

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, xslt, itext

From my ASP.net MVC application, I am generating PDFs using iTextSharp and XSLT as the template. The pages are supposed to be landscape oriented.

The PDF document in landscape mode by following.

```
new Document(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate(), marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom);
```

From the XSLT I get the HTML and construct PDF content as following:

```
public void ParseXhtmlContents(string xhtml)
{
    //Instantiate handler
    var elementhandler = new ElementHandler();
    //Bind a reader to text
    using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(xhtml))
    {
        //Parse
        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(elementhandler, sr);
    }

    //Loop through each element
    foreach (var element in elementhandler.Elements)
    {
        var div = element as PdfDiv;
        if (div != null)
            foreach (var table in div.Content.OfType<PdfPTable>())
            {
                table.HeaderRows = 1;
            }
        _iTextDocument.Add(element);
    }
}
```

After generating the PDF bytes, I am trying to add page footer as following

```
private byte[] AddPageHeader(byte[] pdf, float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop, float marginBottom)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
        var reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
        var totalPage = reader.NumberOfPages;
        var pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);
        var document = new Document(pageSize, marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();
        var contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
        var pageIndex = 0;
        for (var page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            document.NewPage();
            pageIndex++;
            var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, page);
            contentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);
            contentByte.BeginText();
            var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            contentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 6);
            contentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "-     " + pageIndex.ToString() + "     -", 300f, 20, 0);
            contentByte.EndText();
            contentByte.SaveState();
            contentByte.SetColorStroke(new PdfSpotColor("black", new BaseColor(0, 0, 0)), 100);
            contentByte.SetLineWidth(0.25f);
            contentByte.Rectangle(20, 45, 572, 0.25f);
            contentByte.FillStroke();
            contentByte.RestoreState();
        }
        startingPageNumber = pageIndex;
        document.Close();
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

If I skip the part where I add page number I am able to generate the PDF in landscape orientation with content displayed in right order, however when I add footer I am getting the following result, the rendered page is in portrait.

Please refer the attached image for output:

[image]

Help me out on where I am going wrong, thanks.

Comment: 1. You create new pages but you do not set their page size. 2. You copy page by adding them as templates to other pages, a lot of information is possibly lost here. 1 and 2 result in 'loosing' your page orientation

Comment: Since you parse to elements first and add these to a an iText document, the better approach to solve this problem would be through page-events. Have a look at this example form iText in action: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5#228-moviehistory2.java

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong

I changed the document creating code as following:

```
var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1), marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom);
```

and added a footer template similar to the above:

```
contentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex).Height);
```

Comment: You patched a bad solution to somehow work. A good solution would have used a `PdfStamper` instead.

Comment: @mkl I will surely look into `PdfStamper` in future but the work is a bit urgent and can not change implementation as of now. Thank you